# Redirect 404 Errors to Servlet instead of JSP Page?

Tags: jsp, servlets, custom-error-pages

So I saw multiple threads about how to redirect 404 Error requests to a custom JSP Page by adding the following in the web.xml:

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/404page.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

The problem with this method is that the URL displays the following page in this structure:

```
www.mydomain.com/404page.jsp
```

The **.jsp** part bums me out as all the other pages are mapped through Servlets and therefore the **.jsp** is not visible in them.

How can I redirect the user to a Servlet instead of a `404page.jsp` JSP page? Such that the URL is:

```
www.mydomain.com/404
```

Is this possible? If not, what's the way to hide the .jsp part of the URL?

Comment: Have you tried to put <location>/404</location> ?

Comment: This question is strange. Normally URL of error page is not shown in browser's address bar as it's by default displayed by a **forward** not a redirect. Moreover, error pages should be placed in `/WEB-INF` folder to prevent endusers from directly accessing (and bookmarking/sharing/indexing) them. I suggest you to take a step back and investigate why in your case they behave as if they're redirected. This is in first place Wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a 404Handler Servlet and map it like below

```
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>404Handler</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/404</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/404</location>
</error-page>
```

Comment: What's `404`? Is that the Servlet name?

Comment: It works thanks! :) However my 404 doesn't get called when I enter a wrong URL. It still shows a Browser based error saying 'Error 404'. Why doesn't it detect 404 errors?

Comment: you need to specity this is an error page 
  eg:
  
  <%@ page language="java" isErrorPage="true" %>